# HTML,PHP and Apache vs Java Spring and JBoss

Tags: java, php, html, spring, jboss

I'm very confused about which of these I should be useing. I am an experienced Java Swing developer, however, I have recently become interested in web applications.

I started learning about HTML+CSS+PHP with Apache for developing a basic web applications. However, after some research I began wondering how to incorporate my existing Java Classes with a web interface. That is what has lead me to Spring.

1. Is spring intended to be an alternative to the HTML+CSS+PHP?
2. What is the best route to use my existing Java Classes with a browser based interface?

Comment: since you are a java guy already, forget about PHP. maybe try simple servlet + jsp first, then move to spring.

Comment: Regardless of what you use for back end, you will still need HTML and CSS for the front end. If you want to use existing Java Classes, then PHP is out of the question (it's another language). Other than that. choose a language and read some tutorials. If you like it and it works, use it. If it doesn't, try another language.

Comment: Here is where I'm confused. From my research I thought php was server side and that JSP was for client side. Is this not accurate?